# DbUpdateException on SaveChanges if child foreign key already exists - in Entity Framework Code First

Tags: c#, .net, sql, entity-framework, orm

[ *Using Code First DbContext with Entity Framework 5.0 RC* ]

#### Entity with 2 Navigational Properties / 2 Foreign Keys

```
public class Compositon
{

    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string SimpletonId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("SimpletonId")]
    public Simpleton Simpleton { get; set; }

    public string CompanitonId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CompanitonId")]
    public Companiton Companiton { get; set; }
}
```

#### First Pass - SaveChanges to Empty Database Works

```
var composition = new Compositon();
compositon.Id = "UniquePrimaryKey";
var simpleton = new Simpleton();
// This foreign key does not exist in database yet
simpleton.Id = "Simpleton1";
composition.Simpleton = simpleton;
var companiton = new Companiton();
companiton.Id = "SomeOther1";
composition.Companiton = companiton;
// Repositor references the DbContext
Repositor.Compositons.Add(composition);
Repositor.SaveChanges();
```

#### Second Pass - Existing Child Foreign Key Leads to Parent Fault

```
var composition = new Compositon();
compositon.Id = "AnotherUniquePrimaryKey";
var simpleton = new Simpleton();
// This foreign key already exists in database
simpleton.Id = "Simpleton1";
composition.Simpleton = simpleton;
var companiton = new Companiton();
companiton.Id = "SomeOther2";
composition.Companiton = companiton;
Repositor.Compositons.Add(composition);
Repositor.SaveChanges();
```

`DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries.`

*I need to be able save these parent classes into the database, because they are unique even though they sometimes contain a navigational property that is already stored - how can I save the parent from this child primary key conflict?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second pass you will need to retrieve the existing `Simpleton` from the `DbContext`. I'm guessing that you could do that like this:

```
`simpleton = Repositor.Simpletons.First(s => s.Id == "Simpleton1");`
```

Currently, you're creating a brand new one, which the Entity Framework tries to insert as such, hence the key violation.

Comment: Indeed! The replacement was `var simpleton = Repositor.Simpletons.Find("Simpleton1"); if (simpleton == null)
{ simpleton = new Simpleton();                    
simpleton.Id = "Simpleton1";    
}` - I was hoping this would be done automagically though, now I have to implement this procedure as many times as I have child properties ...

Comment: You could add a `FirstOrNew(string id)` extension method to `IEnumerable<T> where T : IIdentifierOwner, new` and use that instead. `IIdentifierOwner` would have a string `Id` property which could be got and set...